# angular2 meteor ionic - cannot use namespace Observable as a type

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, ionic2

I'm following [this tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/chats-page) trying my best not to hate angular with all my being. The tutorial uses Typescript and Angular2 and Ionic, 3 tools which I don't entirely understand, but that's like... why I'm doing a tutorial in the first place. My experience in web development was 2.0 with Django, and a lot of front-end so I know Javascript very well, but this is confusing me.

This is the relevant code:

```
// chats.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Moment from 'moment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Chat, MessageType } from '../../../../imports/models';

import template from './chats.html';

@Component({
    template
});

export class ChatsPage {
    chats: Observable<Chat[]>;

    constructor() {
        this.chats = this.findChats();
    }

    private findChats(): Observable<Chat[]> {
        return Observable.of([
            {
                _id: '0',
                title: 'Ethan Gonzalez',
                picture: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/1.jpg',
                lastMessage: {
                  content: 'You on your way?',
                  createdAt: Moment().subtract(1, 'hours').toDate(),
                  type: MessageType.TEXT
                }
            },
     // dummy data here
```

Second file:

```
// app.components.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { ChatsPage } from '../pages/chats/chats';
import template from "./app.html";

@Component({
    template
});

export class MyApp {
    rootPage = ChatsPage;

    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            if (platform.is('cordova')) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
                Splashscreen.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run Meteor I get these errors:

```
client/imports/pages/chats/chats.ts (13, 12): Cannot use namespace 'Observable' as a type.
client/imports/pages/chats/chats.ts (19, 26): Cannot use namespace 'Observable' as a type.
client/imports/app/app.components.ts (14, 27): Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
```

Comment: Did you tried to run `npm install` again? If not, try now.

Comment: @DiegoCardozo it didn't work, but it did leave a bunch of messages about how `@angular/some-package requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed`. I tried `npm install rxjs` (which should already be available) and now it's a bunch of different messages. I'll try installing all of them and see if that changes anything

Comment: @DiegoCardozo nope. Still nothing. same errors

Comment: Can you publish a repository with your current setup so I can reproduce the problem?  That will be so much easier than me trying to recreate your setup myself.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen here: https://github.com/yuvii/Trying-out-Angular

Comment: I haven't changed anything, but now I get a different error: `Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.` and another one: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Chat[]>'`. I am so confused as to what is happening

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I'm figuring out the latest bug on my own. It seems Observable package changed behaviour, so I'm ok with that (I need to do `import { of } from 'rxjs'` instead of what's in the tutorial) but if you have any idea why I initially got that weird bug I'd love to know since I haven't changed anything to make it go away and it just... did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW at this point: I can reproduce the original errors when I don't have the `node_modules` installed.  And even after I install them, it looks like the barbatus:typescript build plugin is buggy and doesn't invalidate its cache, so it still shows the original errors.  If I delete `.meteor/local/.typescript-cache`, then the installed `node_modules` are recognized.  In general I don't trust barbatus:typescript (it tries to be clever and does too much complex stuff that ends up causing problems), but I don't have an alternative that I can recommend for general use at this point.  If you like, you could [file an issue](https://github.com/barbatus/typescript) and see if barbatus will address this particular problem.

The `Cannot use namespace ... as a type` error seems to be a consequence of your `declarations.d.ts` file doing `declare module '*';`.  The error doesn't make sense to me, so I filed [a TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27311).

Comment: Thank you. It's comforting to know it's not me going crazy but an actual bug. I'd love to know if there are alternatives. The tutorial says that the declarations.d.ts is needed to support third party libs that don't support typescript. I don't understand why cause this is new to me but I assume I need this file.

Comment: The alternative is to remove the `declare module "*";`, and each time you add a third-party library that doesn't have type declarations, manually add `declare module "...";` statements for the specific modules you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

instead of

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
```